# "Only one of `path` or `inline` may be set" on vagrant up

Tags: ansible, vagrant, vlad-drupal

I am trying to use vlad to install drupal using vagrant on windows.
I installed vagrant.
I have installed Cygwin using babun and finally I got to install ansible.
When vagrant up I get : "Only one of `path` or `inline` may be set" error.

```
{ vlad-master }  » vagrant up                                                     ~/vlad-master 1
Found project settings file: C:/Users/maggie/.babun/cygwin/home/maggie/vlad-master/vlad_guts/vlad_settings.yml

Bringing machine 'vlad' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> vlad: Running triggers before up...
==> vlad: Executing pre 'provision' setup trigger
==> vlad: Executing command "ansible-galaxy install -r vlad_guts/playbooks/requirements.yml --force"...
==> vlad: - extracting aberdeencloud_cli to /home/maggie/vlad-master/vlad_guts/playbooks/ext_roles/aberdeencloud_cli
==> vlad: - aberdeencloud_cli was installed successfully
==> vlad: - extracting pantheon_cli to /home/maggie/vlad-master/vlad_guts/playbooks/ext_roles/pantheon_cli
==> vlad: - pantheon_cli was installed successfully
==> vlad: - extracting imagemagick to /home/maggie/vlad-master/vlad_guts/playbooks/ext_roles/imagemagick
==> vlad: - imagemagick was installed successfully
==> vlad: - extracting sendmail to /home/maggie/vlad-master/vlad_guts/playbooks/ext_roles/sendmail
==> vlad: - sendmail was installed successfully
==> vlad: - extracting tomcat to /home/maggie/vlad-master/vlad_guts/playbooks/ext_roles/tomcat
==> vlad: - tomcat was installed successfully
==> vlad: - extracting solr to /home/maggie/vlad-master/vlad_guts/playbooks/ext_roles/solr
==> vlad: - solr was installed successfully
==> vlad: - adding dependency: hashbangcode.tomcat
==> vlad: - extracting drush to /home/maggie/vlad-master/vlad_guts/playbooks/ext_roles/drush
==> vlad: - drush was installed successfully
==> vlad: - extracting platformsh_cli to /home/maggie/vlad-master/vlad_guts/playbooks/ext_roles/platformsh_cli
==> vlad: - platformsh_cli was installed successfully
==> vlad: - downloading role 'tomcat', owned by hashbangcode
==> vlad: - downloading role from https://github.com/hashbangcode/ansible-role-tomcat/archive/master.tar.gz
==> vlad: - extracting hashbangcode.tomcat to /home/maggie/vlad-master/vlad_guts/playbooks/ext_roles/hashbangcode.tomcat
==> vlad: - hashbangcode.tomcat was installed successfully
==> vlad: Command execution finished.
==> vlad: Executing 'up' setup trigger
==> vlad: Creating C:/Users/maggie/.babun/cygwin/home/maggie/vlad-master/vlad_guts/host.ini
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

shell provisioner:
* Only one of `path` or `inline` may be set.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [vagrant shell provisioning](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html) documentation

> The shell provisioner takes various options. One of `inline` or `path` is
>   required:
>
> - `inline` (string) - Specifies a shell command inline to execute on the
>     remote machine. See the inline scripts section below for more
>     information.
> - `path` (string) - Path to a shell script to upload and execute. It can
>     be a script relative to the project Vagrantfile or a remote script
>     (like a gist).

so you can either have

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell",
    inline: "echo Hello, World"
end
```

or

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "script.sh"
end
```

You can review your shell provisioner form your Vagrantfile and make sure the provisioner does not have `path` and `inline` within the same block, it must be one **or** the other